# PL/SQL Update values using DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

```
DECLARE
    ins NUMBER := 0;
    upd NUMBER := 0;
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT cid
        FROM tbl_cust
        WHERE cid 
        IN ('1','2','3','4');
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
        INSERT INTO tbl2 (id_tbl2, name_tbl2)
        VALUES(rec.cid, DECODE(rec.cid, '1', 'A',
                                        '2', 'B',
                                        '3', 'C',
                                        '4', 'D'));
        ins := ins + 1;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('Updated: ' || ins);
    dbms_output.put_line('Inserted: ' || upd);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
            UPDATE tbl2 set name_tbl2 = DECODE(rec.cid, '1', 'A', 
                                                        '2', 'B',
                                                        '3', 'C',
                                                        '4', 'D')
            WHERE cust_cust_code = rec.cid;
            upd := upd + 1;    
        END LOOP;
        dbms_output.put_line('Updated: ' || upd);
        dbms_output.put_line('Inserted: ' || ins);
END;
```

when running this code for the first time and there are no values from tbl_cust that is the same as tbl2, the output is like this:

Updated: 0

Inserted: 4

which is correct. In the 2nd run the output is like this:

Updated: 4

Inserted: 0

which is also correct.
But when i delete for example cid '1' and '3' from the database, the result is like this:

Updated: 4

Inserted: 2

The output that I wanted is like this after deleting cid '1' and '3':

Updated: 2

Inserted: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop through all the records in case of the update.
That's why you are getting 4 updates instead of expected 2.

Instead, you should update only in the case of the `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` exception and only the row that caused the exception.

Try something like this.

```
DECLARE
    ins NUMBER := 0;
    upd NUMBER := 0;
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT cid
        FROM tbl_cust
        WHERE cid 
        IN ('1','2','3','4');
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
        begin 
           INSERT INTO tbl2 (id_tbl2, name_tbl2)
           VALUES(rec.cid, DECODE(rec.cid, '1', 'A',
                                        '2', 'B',
                                        '3', 'C',
                                        '4', 'D'));
           ins := ins + 1;
        EXCEPTION   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
           UPDATE tbl2 set name_tbl2 = DECODE(rec.cid, '1', 'A',
                                        '2', 'B',
                                        '3', 'C',
                                        '4', 'D'));
           WHERE cust_cust_code = rec.cid;
           upd := upd + 1;
           continue; 
         end;    
    END LOOP;
        dbms_output.put_line('Updated: ' || upd);
        dbms_output.put_line('Inserted: ' || ins);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your logic. When one insertion fails your code drops into the exception handler, starts a new cursor and *updates all the records*. The program then terminates after the first failure. So your third run does this:

```
Inserted: 1  -- insert where CID=1 succeeded
Updated: 4   -- insert where CID=2 failed
```

Except that only three TBL2 records were actually updated because you count the rows in the loop not how many rows were updated. what you should have done was `upd := update + sql%count;`, which only increments the counter when rows are actually updated.

What you wanted to do was this:

```
DECLARE
    ins NUMBER := 0;
    upd NUMBER := 0;
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT cid
        FROM tbl_cust
        WHERE cid 
        IN ('1','2','3','4');
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
        begin
            INSERT INTO tbl2 (id_tbl2, name_tbl2)
            VALUES(rec.cid, DECODE(rec.cid, '1', 'A',
                                            '2', 'B',
                                            '3', 'C',
                                            '4', 'D'));
            ins := ins + sql%rowcount;
        exception
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
               UPDATE tbl2 set name_tbl2 = DECODE(rec.cid, '1', 'A', 
                                                            '2', 'B',
                                                            '3', 'C',
                                                            '4', 'D')
                WHERE id_tbl2 = rec.cid;
                upd := upd + sql%rowcount;   
         end;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('Inserted: ' || ins);
    dbms_output.put_line('Updated: ' || upd);

END;
/
```

But what you **should do** is use a MERGE to implement this logic:

```
merge into tbl2
    using ( select * from tbl_cust ) q
    on (q.cid = tbl2.id_tbl2)
when not matched then 
    insert  (id_tbl2, name_tbl2)
    values (q.cid, DECODE(q.cid, '1', 'A',
                                 '2', 'B',
                                 '3', 'C',
                                 '4', 'D'))
when matched then 
    update 
    set tbl2.name_tbl2 = DECODE(q.cid, '1', 'W', 
                                        '2', 'X',
                                        '3', 'Y',
                                        '4', 'Z')
/
```

Note: the WHEN MATCHED branch uses different values to make it easy to see what happens in your third run.